# How to install elasticsearch5.6 in macos?

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

Now I am not able to install elasticsearch5.6 in my macos.
brew can't find the formula elasticsearch@5.6.

I executed following command line.

brew install elasticsearch@5.6

but it shows following result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfljF.png)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: its been a long time. It would be great if you can accept and upvote my answer if it helped you resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You can install Elasticsearch version `5.6` as a `.tar.gz` archive for MacOS using the following link :

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-5-6-0

After downloading, run the command `tar -xzvf myfile.tar.gz`, you can also refer to these other methods for [compressing and uncompressing tar files in macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/apdc52250ee-4659-4751-9a3a-8b7988150530/mac)

Answer (score 0):

To download elastic search 5.6 an install on a simple command you can use:

> wget
> https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.6.0.tar.gz
> && tar -xzvf elasticsearch-5.6.0.tar.gz

note: if you don't have wget, to install it just run `brew install wget`

Otherwise if you don't want to install this version of elasticsearch you can use a docker image:

- Install Docker.
- Run this command:
  `docker run -it --rm -p 9200:9200 elasticsearch:5.6-alpine`